# Searching for a no-dialogue short film from the 90s where a man takes the top of his skull off

Tags: story-identification

Set in a city, extremely dark and gritty, involving a guy going through some kind of deep psychological torment, possibly drug-addiction related.  At one point he gets out of bed and takes the top of his skull off, revealing his brain.  I saw it sometime in the 90s and it was probably made around that time.